# transfer product from a record type to another record type

Tags: record

I have created a product in my "products" record type, now I want to transfer the product into my "product archive" record type and set it as private so that no one can see it. How can i do this?

Comment: Do you want to create a button to automate this?

Comment: This question needs clarification. Do you want to know how to manually change the recordtype or automatically via a Workflow/field update or code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the Record Type field is on the page layout firstly to allow you to change the record type, and secondly you need to make the product object private and use a combination of sharing rules to limit access to the archive record type and permit access to the product record type.

If you do some research into sharing rules you will find the information you require.